# Jest testing library - multiple calls to load data on click event

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a load more button call on an onClick fireEvent but I am having trouble simulating the click to trigger a load data.

component:

```
class Items extends Component {

  // states
  
  componentDidMount() {
     this.getData()
  }

  getData() { ... 
     // get data from state - pagination # and data size
  }

  onLoadMore() {
      // increment pagination & offset on states
      this.getData()
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div className='container'>
         {items.map((item, i) => {
              return (
                 <div className='item-box'>
                     // item info
                 </div>
              )
           }
         )}
         <button onClick={this.onLoadMore}>Load More</button>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

test:

```
it('load more data on load more button click', () => {
    const Items = require('./default').default

    // set initial load values: initVals (2 items)
    // set second call values: secondVals (4 items)

    Items.prototype.getData = jest.fn()
    Items.prototype.getData.mockReturnValue(initVals)
    Items.prototype.getData.mockReturnValue(secondVals)

    const { container } = render(
      <Items
        fields={{ loadMore: true }}
      />
    )

    const button = screen.getByText('Load More')
    fireEvent.click(button)

    expect(container.querySelectorAll('.item-box').length).toBe(2)
    expect(container.querySelectorAll('.item-box').length).toBe(4)
  })
```

So this only reads the last call, finding 4 items.

Calling `.mockReturnValue()` multiple times has only yielded me the last call instead of it consecutively. I know I am using it wrong but I can't figure out the sequence of running this. My goal is to initialize the component with first values (load 2 items), then on click, it loads more (4 items).

Help?

Comment: Can you provide the code of the component?

Comment: @slideshowp2 updated

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call [`mockReturnValueOnce`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-return-values) instead of `mockReturnValue`, and you definitely need to move your first assertion before clicking the event. Also, I think your second assertion should expect `6`, not `4`.

The order of operations for your test should be:

- Set up mocks
- Render component
- Assert initial value on load
- Simulate click event
- Assert value after click.

Here is a simple example that demonstrates this concept:

```js
// src/Demo.js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Demo = ({ loadText }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setText(loadText())}>Load</button>
      <p data-testid="data">{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

```js
// src/Demo.test.js
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import Demo from "./Demo";

test("callbacks", () => {
  const myMock = jest.fn();
  myMock.mockReturnValueOnce(2);
  myMock.mockReturnValueOnce(4);

  render(<Demo loadText={myMock} />);

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));
  expect(screen.getByTestId("data")).toHaveTextContent("2");

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));
  expect(screen.getByTestId("data")).toHaveTextContent("4");
});
```

Also, the way you are mocking this function (`Items.prototype.getData = jest.fn()`) seems odd to me. I recommend you explore other options, such as (1) mocking out axios or similar library, (2) mocking out a redux store, or (3) mocking out props that you pass to this component.